# New code cannot be written by pdflatex - error due to Pygmentize output

Tags: pdftex

The minted package was working very well till one day the Anaconda package broke due to other reasons and I had to do a fresh install of the Anaconda installation and Pygments library from conda.

After that - any new code included on the file is not accepted and an error is thrown. Incidentally, any old code written before the crash, even if copy+pasted ahead of the book, gets printed, but any new code simply gives an error.
The command I am using is below and the error below it;

```
pdflatex -shell-escape book.tex
```

```
[43] [44]Access is denied.
system returned with code 1


! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.2537 \end{minted}
```

Update:

It simply refuses to write any code:

```
(./_minted-book/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle) (./_minted-book/default.pygstyle)Access is denied.
system returned with code 1


! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.443 \end{minted}
```

Comment: Without further information, there are a lot of possibilities what went wrong. My guess - did you have renamed the file you are compiling?

Comment: No files are renamed. it simply refuses to write any code now:

Answer (score 1):

Pygments installed using Conda is not working. I remember that in my earlier install - i had installed pygments using pip.

To test this, I created a virtual environment and installed only Python using conda and Pygments using pip and it works well again!

Ideally - pygments installed using conda should also work.

Comment: This is interesting. I am not using anaconda, so I never heard about your situation. Please, contact about that mr. Poore, author of pythontex package.

Comment: Yep - I did that in parallel - https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/261. Thanks!